# How many quirks does deku have?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I was curious, because I have only just caught up with the anime, and I saw

> he unlocked another quirk.  So how many does he have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's explained in episode 98, "That Which Is Inherited", that the Quirks of the previous One For All users have mixed in with its core, and they will unlock over time. He's told that he will unlock six Quirks in total, starting with "Blackwhip" which appeared in that episode.

Comment: Which means that, including One For All itself, Deku has (or will have) **seven** Quirks in total. Considering that he's the ninth One For All wielder, and both he and All Might were Quirkless, the math checks out.